# Hibernate Mappings vs Database Mappings

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

Hibernate provides annotations (OneToOne, OneToMany, etc) to maintain table relationships.
We can achieve same at database level by implement PK and FK.

My question is, In spring boot project what will be the best way to handle these relations, shall I handle at code level or only at database level.

Comment: You should add these relationships in hibernate entity classes in your code.

Comment: Do you have any suitable explanation for this or any article which confirm the same

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done with both at the database level and the code level. Because at the code level give clarity to the java objects and at the database level it gives clarity for the database level.

Comment: But adding at code level will cause many problems. like maintain their cascading, loading(eager or lazy) and some hibernate related limitations